# how to make a list from json string

Tags: json, r, date

I have a JSON file "adjFloatTest.data" .In R, i read the field "Volume" from that file using the following code:

```
json <- fromJSON("adjFloatTest.data")
volume <- json$volume
```

the value of the volume is as follows

```
> volume
$AAPL
$AAPL[[1]]
1980-12-12 
  16751200 

$AAPL[[2]]
1980-12-15 
 100424081 

$AAPL[[3]]
1980-12-16 
 0.1177374 

$AAPL[[4]]
1980-12-17 
   7164476 

$AAPL[[5]]
1980-12-18 
   5364366
```

Each elements corresponding to company,date,value. I want to store each dates into a list. How it is possible?

Comment: You should give reproducible sample input data as well as format of desired output? what do you mean by list here?

Comment: can you run `dput(volume)` and paste the output in your question

Comment: Why the downvote to this question? am i missing something?

Comment: probably because after repeated request from different people you still haven't provided reproducible data and format of desired output

Comment: The downvotes are because you have several folks who are trying to offer you their time and help, but your question is lacking useful data which, for whatever reason, you seem to keep missing the multiple requests for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the list of dates

```
sapply(volume,names)
```

Comment: but this gives a list with no values. The value of this output is $AAPL
NULL

Comment: @DinoopNair you don't give a reproducible example Sir! And you look very exigent about the result! can you dput(volume) as asked by others. If you don't understand , type dput(volume) !

Answer (score -1):

the following should work:

```
 sapply(volume, function(x) lapply(x, "[[", 1))
```

---

but a reproducible example that could be copied+pasted would be helpful.

If the above doesnt work, please use something like `dput(volume[1:2])` to offer some workable sample data.

Comment: this function is for storing the values into the list. Actually i need to store all dates into the list.

Comment: @DinoopNair, did you not read the 2nd part?   You have not provided a reproducable example and you are asking folks to figure out the structure of your data.